# Linux CentOS 7 autofs does not mount network share after reboot

Tags: linux, automount, centos7

Problem:
I have CentOS 7 Linux VM with cifs installed. I added a mount point using autofs where the whole idea was to automatically mount a network share every time VM boots. However, when I run this command:

```
    ls /mnt/vmshare/trinity
```

I get

```
    ls: cannot access /mnt/vmshare/trinity: No such file or directory
```

Workaround:
What I'm having to do is run this command after each reboot

```
    /sbin/service autofs start
```

Then I can see the files in trinity.

Maybe autofs does not even start by default on reboot. How to make sure autofs starts on reboot? Or in general, how to solve my problem above?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm also not sure this question should be here... It might need to be migrated to superuser, serverfault or something... so many options nowadays... :D

Answer (score 2):

for CentOS 7:

## systemctl enable autofs

check with:

## systemctl is-enabled autofs

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall exactly what I used to figure this one out, but maybe it will get you on the right track.

I did some research on this a few years ago, and I believe the term you're looking for is "persistent mount."

You'll need to create or find the local mount point for your network directory.  For instance, in mine..  /media/disco/disknamehere.../.../Share

This must be added to **/etc/fstab** with the correct options in place.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
chkconfig autofs on
```

that will enable autofs service to start on boot.